# I wanna use select query, but "–" and "-" is different in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

i need help.

First of all sorry for my bad English.

so, I want to select a value in MYSQL, but I wanna SQL to read "–" and "-" is the same value.

like "Red – Apple" is the same as "Red - Apple".

Is there any query for this?

Thanks Before

Comment: You may try to look for a collation which treates both dashes as the same symbol (I have not seen such collation). But the best solution is to normalize the data (for example, replace all long dashed with regular ones).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
where col regexp '^Red [–-] Apple$'
```